# pine script - cannot call plotchar with arguments

Tags: pine-script

I can't figure out how to print the letters F or T based on the bool value of the openable variable.
I have tried various ways: omitting or not the name of the topic, using a variable defined before, but I keep getting the error "Cannot call plotchar with arguments (literal bool, char=series[string])".
This is my code, somebody can clarify me? Thank you

```
//@version=4

//___________

sma= sma(close, 1008)

variation_raw= (((close*100)/sma)-100) // variazione prezzo corrente/media mobile 7gg

toward= if variation_raw>=0 // direzione della variazione (short, long)
    true
else 
    false

variation= abs(variation_raw)

lineColor= if variation<=2.5 
    color.blue
else if variation<=5 
    color.green
else if variation<=9
    color.yellow
else 
    color.red

//_______________

var openable= false

var ref= 0

//__________

if lineColor== color.red
    openable := false

if lineColor== color.blue or lineColor== color.green
    openable := true

//______

plot(close, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=lineColor)
    
plotchar(true, char=openable ? 't':'f')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this decision will suit you

```
plotchar(openable, char='t')
plotchar(not(openable), char='f')
```